# SQL merge two rows and fill columns with missing values from another row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am not able to merge rows and need help in figuring out.
Idea is whenever there are multiple rows with same groupid then I would like to
merge both rows and fill the empty column with one that has a value.
This particularly problematic that I would never know which column will be empty, and there is a possibility that groupid may be same in more than 3 rows(remotely but possible). Here is sample sql data

```
    if object_id('tempdb..#deleteme') is not null drop table #deleteme;

    CREATE TABLE #deleteme(
        [groupid] [varchar](82) NULL,
        [col_1] [varchar](5) NULL,
        [col_2] [varchar](5) NULL,
        [col_3] [varchar](5) NULL,
        [col_date] [datetime] NULL
    )

    INSERT #deleteme ([groupid], [col_1], [col_2], [col_3], [col_date]) VALUES (N'0022017', N'100', N'0.0', N'0.0', CAST(N'2017-11-24 14:09:44.537' AS DateTime));
    INSERT #deleteme ([groupid], [col_1], [col_2], [col_3], [col_date]) VALUES (N'0032203', N'0', N'1.70', N'0.0', CAST(N'2017-11-24 13:44:58.797' AS DateTime));
    INSERT #deleteme ([groupid], [col_1], [col_2], [col_3], [col_date]) VALUES (N'0043108', N'1', N'0.0', N'0.950', CAST(N'2017-11-24 14:11:17.740' AS DateTime));
    INSERT #deleteme ([groupid], [col_1], [col_2], [col_3], [col_date]) VALUES (N'0043108', N'0', N'1.25', N'0.0', CAST(N'2017-11-24 14:11:09.203' AS DateTime));

    groupid col_1   col_2   col_3   col_date
    0022017 100     0.0     0.0     2017-11-24 14:09:44.537
    0032203 0       1.70    0.0     2017-11-24 13:44:58.797
    0043108 1       0.0     0.950   2017-11-24 14:11:17.740--merge this
    0043108 0       1.25    0.0     2017-11-24 14:11:09.203--and merge this
```

The desired output which I am not able to get done using sql is as below

```
groupid col_1   col_2   col_3   col_date
0043108 1       1.25    0.950   2017-11-24 14:11:17.740
0043108 1       1.25    0.950   2017-11-24 14:11:09.203
```

I have omitted other 2 unique rows on purpose from the result, I hope some one can help me figure this out. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "merge" rows. If what you mean is that when a value is 0 in col1, col2 or col3 you pick the value from that column in other row with the same id, then you should decide if that value is the MAX, or it is calculated in a different way. For a MAX solution it could look like this:

```
SELECT d1.groupid, CASE WHEN d1.col_1 > 0 THEN d1.col_1 ELSE xt.col1Merged END AS Col1
, CASE WHEN d1.col_1 > 0 THEN d1.col_2 ELSE xt.col2Merged END AS Col2
, CASE WHEN d1.col_3 > 0 THEN d1.col_3 ELSE xt.col3Merged END AS Col3
FROM #deleteme d1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT d.groupid, MAX(d.col_1) AS col1Merged, MAX(d.col_2) AS col2Merged, 
    MAX(d.col_3) AS col3Merged
    FROM #deleteme d
    GROUP by d.groupid
) xt ON xt.groupid = d1.groupid
```

Comment: Thanks...my logic was similar but was not using max in join table.
Again thank you very much..let me see if I can implement this

Comment: If it is the sum of the other columns, you can change the MAX with SUM in the inner table and you are good to go. If there is some custom logic then I guess it will be more difficult :)

Comment: While working with your example, following gives me what I need as well, can you see if there is anything wrong with this approach?(its from your code)
SELECT d.groupid, MAX(d.col_1) AS col1Merged, MAX(d.col_2) AS col2Merged, 
    MAX(d.col_3) AS col3Merged
    FROM #deleteme d
    GROUP by d.groupid

Comment: You mean running only the inner query? I don't think it is correct. For one thing, it would group the two columns of your sample into 1 keeping only the max of each column, and you would lose one of the dates. Plus, if you had 3 rows with groupid 0043108 and col_1 with values 0, 1, 2, all the three rows would have in output col_1 = 2, while I understood from your explanation that you only wanted to replace values with 0 (empty)

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
SELECT groupid, 
(SELECT max(col_1) FROM #deleteme dtm1 WHERE dtm1.groupid = dtm.groupid) AS col_1,
(SELECT max(col_2) FROM #deleteme dtm1 WHERE dtm1.groupid = dtm.groupid) AS col_2,
(SELECT max(col_3) FROM #deleteme dtm1 WHERE dtm1.groupid = dtm.groupid) AS col_3, col_date 
FROM #deleteme dtm
```