# Combine Rows According To Event Timestamp

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

Am trying to wrap my head around what's the best postgresql query to merge the below table as one timestamp record row that contains both the user_id and tx_id instead of it showing up as 2 rows ?

The data type for user_id and tx_id are strings if that helps with clarity.

Current table:

```
timestamp      user_id       tx_id
4/8/2021 9:21  fa6f6229906
4/8/2021 9:21                2
```

Expected result:

```
timestamp      user_id       tx_id
4/8/2021 9:21  fa6f6229906   2
```

Comment: Redshift of Postgres? Those are two very different database products.

Answer (score 0):

You can try max().

```
select timestamp
     , max(user_id) user_id
     , max(tx_id) tx_id
  from some_table 
 group by timestamp;
```

Caution: You should avoid creating a column name timestamp. Timestamp is a quasi reserved word Postgres and a SQL reserved word and a data type. It is very poor practice using a it as a column name.

Comment: @Belayar Tried this and the resulting query data is the same. I've had some initial success using SUM only if the string data contains numbers only. It wouldn't work if the string data contains alpha numeric as what we have in the user_id column.

Answer (score 0):

I found the inner join solution from this post works just nice for what we need.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48846014/16081058